# Replacing a dot with an underscore in a file using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I was trying to edit the output of a file using sed.  The contents of file are

```
cat /tmp/Group_RM
t.p@k.p
t.m@k.k
```

I was trying to get the output as:

```
cat /tmp/Group_RM
t_p@k_p
t_m@k_k
```

I tried the below command but the output looked odd:

```
cat /tmp/Group_RM | sed 's/./_/g'
```

Output is:

```
____ ___
_______
```

sed is replacing all characters with underscores. When I tried to replace "_" with ".", sed works perfectly.

Comment: Please do not sign your posts, and note that you should indent code with four spaces, or select it and press `Ctrl-K` or click the `{}` code button. No need for HTML `<br>`s. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to escape the `.` like `\.`. `.` is a special metacharacter which *matches any single character*.

```
$ sed 's/\./_/g' Group_RM
t_p@k_p
t_m@k_k
```

On a side note, `cat` is not needed - `sed` can deal with files itself.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that a dot is a special character in regular expressions.
If you mean an actual dot, you need to escape it with \.

Also, you do not need cat, you can give the filename to sed directly.
This works:

```
sed 's/\./_/g' myfile.txt
```